# widget error in manifest - Attribute is missing the Android namespace prefix

Tags: android

I have defined an app widget provider in the manifest, exactly as in https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html

```
<receiver android:name="myWidgetProvider>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data 
                android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                android:resource="@xml/mywidget_info" />
 </receiver>
```

But Eclipse is showing me an error :

`Attribute is missing the Android namespace prefix`

on the line `"android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE"`

What's wrong?

Comment: please add (") double quote after this text myWidgetProvider.

Comment: @Haresh you should put that as answer

Answer (score 2):

**You have missing (") double quote after this text myWidgetProvider.**

```
<receiver android:name="myWidgetProvider">
```

Answer (score -1):

Stupid mistake. I forgot to close the quote at :

```
<receiver android:name="myWidgetProvider">
```

Comment: that it's i exactly know you in my comment.